# Remove Notification Area Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gnome

I've been using Ubuntu for 15 minutes, and I have a question.

How do I remove this thing:

[image]

This "notification area" annoyance that pops up whenever you think about touching something at the bottom of your screen?

It's driving me crazy! :D

Comment: this isn't Unity, so unclear how it was fixed with Unity Tweak Tool...

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else needs to know, I deactivated it by installing `unity-tweak-tool`

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool gnome-tweak-tool
```

In order to run and use it, you'll need to install a lot of things it says are missing.
For me these were:

```
notify-osd
unity-webapps
overlay-scrollbar
```

Inside `unity-tweak-tool`, you can disable things being triggered by moving to the edges. Yay.

Comment: Can you tell me where to find the setting to disable the notification area (or it's popping up)? I don't see any such setting in the tweak tool...